# While using a nested LinerLayout not only I dont get to see my Views inside the 2nd child I also get this : "Element LinerLayout is not allowed here"

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio-4.1

I guess this is the simplest possible xml code for an activity and yet Android Studio  gives this ambiguity error while hovering on it, I would ignore that but the final result in the IDE's layout validation and a physical device is that all those child elements of the second LinerLayout are not appearing at all not even in the blue print view.

I have tried solutions from similar posts and non worked for me:
Restarted the IDE
Restarted the System
Cleaned the project
I appreciate your help.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!--1ok-->
        <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Profile_activity">
          <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1">
          <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
           android:id="@+id/Barrier_horizontal"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
           app:barrierDirection="top"/>
           <ImageView...>    
           </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
           <LinerLayout  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
               <LinerLayout...><!--other elements folded inside it like TextVeiw-->
    <!--Android message while hovering on it===>"Element LinerLayout is not allowed here"-->
               <LinerLayout...><!--other elements folded inside it like TextVeiw-->
    <!--Android message while hovering on it===>"Element LinerLayout is not allowed here"-->
                
        </LinerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You've misspelled "LinearLayout" as "LinerLayout".

Comment: I feel so dumb thank you really !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the IDE provided layout editor and auto suggestion, that will help you to reduce typo errors.

Just change the LinerLayout to **LinearLayout** this will solve your problem.